# Click Event not working on Recharts Pie Label

Tags: reactjs, onclick, pie-chart, recharts

I am working on **Recharts** plugin for a React Project to display a **Piechart** with 2 sections and customized label.

My requirement is to get the value of the pie section on click. I am able to achieve it through adding onClick props to **Pie** tag. But the issue is when i click on the label in the PieCharts, the click event is not triggered.

Some search results say, we cant have click event on svg child elements like rect, circle, text, etc.

Anyone have faced such issues? Please help me how to proceed on this.

> Pie Chart Code

```
const data = [{ name: 'On Time', value: Number(70), mode: 'total' }, 
              { name: 'Delayed', value: Number(30), mode: 'total' }];
const COLORS = ['#008000', '#fa833c'];
<PieChart width={300} height={300} className={'mainPie'}>
    <Pie dataKey="value"
         activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
         labelLine={false}
         label={renderCustomizedLabel}
         data={data}
         cx={150}
         cy={130}
         outerRadius={120}
         innerRadius={60}
         onClick={this.onPieClick}
         fill="#8884d8">
         {data.map((entry, index) => <Cell key={index} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]}/>)}
     </Pie>
 </PieChart>
```

> On Click Event Function

```
onPieClick = (index, data) => {
    console.log('onPieClick'+index.value);
}
```

> Custom Label Codebase

```
const renderCustomizedLabel = ({ cx, cy, midAngle, innerRadius, outerRadius, percent, index, mode}) => {
let radius = innerRadius + (outerRadius - innerRadius) * 0.3;
let x = cx + radius * Math.cos(-midAngle * (Math.PI / 180));    
let y = cy + radius * Math.sin(-midAngle * (Math.PI / 180));
return (
(<g>
        <text x={cx} y={cy} dy={8} textAnchor="middle" fill="black" fontSize="12">DELIVERIES</text>
        <text x={x} y={y} fill="white" textAnchor={x > cx ? 'start' : 'end'} fontSize="12" dominantBaseline="central">
            {(percent * 100).toFixed(2)}%
        </text>
    </g>
);
```

}

Below is the screenshot of the chart.

[image: Pie Chart]

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue with Rechart Bar Chart too. I solved it by setting pointerEvents of the custom label to none.

```
const renderCustomizedLabel = (...) => {
  ...
  return <g style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>...</g>;
};
```

According to MDN, by setting `pointer-events: none`

> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events
>   may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse
>   events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
>   appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
>   capture/bubble phases.

Hence the click event passes through the label and triggers Pie onClick.

Comment: thanks for your response @Alex. Will try out this solution.